# dynamically add JLabel to UI in java on button click using a single object

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create labels each time when a button is clicked. The location of the labels should be changed. It should be above one another each time of click. But it is not working. Not creating any label. I cant even create a single JLabel from the button click listener code. But the execution is happening inside the innermost 'if' statement.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class ChatClient{
static int y=600;
static JLabel label=null;
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
  String defaultMessage = "Enter your message..";
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("FireFly");
  JTextField text = new JTextField(defaultMessage);
  //manipulate the default message in the text field
  text.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent ae){
      if(text.getText().equals(defaultMessage)){
          text.setText("");
      }
   }
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent ae){
      if(text.getText().isEmpty()){
        text.setText(defaultMessage);
      }
    }
  });
  text.setBounds(10,620,295,40);
  frame.add(text);
  JButton button = new JButton("SEND");
  button.setBounds(310,620,80,40);
  button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
  button.setBackground(Color.decode("#11A458"));
  button.setFocusPainted(false);
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
      if(!text.getText().equals(defaultMessage))
      {
        if(!text.getText().isEmpty()){
          label=new JLabel(text.getText());
          label.setBounds(10,y,380,20);
          y=y-20;
          frame.add(label);
          }
      }
    }
  });

  frame.add(button);
  frame.setSize(400,700);
  frame.setLayout(null);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
}
```

Comment: You would need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container any time you add or remove components from it.  Your first big mistake is to use null layouts -- avoid these as they will come back to haunt you, guaranteed.

Comment: Also I do have to wonder if you'd be better off using a JList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling revalidate and repaint on the container after adding your JLabel will tell the GUI to position the new component and to repaint the container so that it shows. e.g.,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (!text.getText().equals(defaultMessage)) {
        if (!text.getText().isEmpty()) {
            label = new JLabel(text.getText());
            label.setBounds(10, y, 380, 20);
            y = y - 20;
            frame.add(label);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, the revalidate isn't absolutely necessary since you're not using a layout manager, but still it's a good idea to include it, since you **should** be using layout managers as null layouts are dangerous and fragile.

Better though to use a JList.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChatClient2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT = 30;
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<String> chatList = new JList<>(listModel);
    private SendAction sendAction = new SendAction("Send");
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    private JButton sendButton = new JButton(sendAction);

    public ChatClient2() {
        chatList.setFocusable(false);
        chatList.setVisibleRowCount(VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatList);

        textField.setAction(sendAction);
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        bottomPanel.add(textField);
        bottomPanel.add(sendButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class SendAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SendAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = textField.getText();
            listModel.add(0, text);
            textField.selectAll();
            textField.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Client2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ChatClient2());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```